# Laravel API Middleware Return JSON all request

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5

My controllers that respond to api request, all respond with data that should be transformed into JSON.

Instead of using `json_encode()` in every controller, I would like to use middleware to just wrap the response. Since these routes for the API are already protected with the `auth:api` middleware which from what I have read is defined within the core of Laravel.

How would I go about adding a method to that middleware that would do all the json processing for me? could

Comment: you can see an example in this repository https://github.com/generationtux/json-middleware , hope it will helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of API's it's very common to return just a model or collection.

If you are doing that a `return $someData` in your API controller, `$someData` will automatically be converted to JSON and returned with the appropriate headers.

Middleware is unnecessary.